# NSDateFormatter problem

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get NSDate from string but its returning nil.
I tried this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2010-05-07T10:12:32UTC"];
NSLog(@"Success date=%@",[date description]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format string expects the date to end with a literal `Z`. But your date ends with the string `UTC`. There are several ways to fix this.

1. Change your date format string to `@"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'UTC'"`.
2. Or, change your date string to `@"2010-05-07T10:12:32Z"`.

Or, you could change your date format string to: `@"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"`. This will recognize some common 3-letter time zone names, such as PDT for Pacific Daylight Time. Unfortunately, however, it will not recognize UTC as a time zone name (you’d have to use “GMT”).

Answer (score 0):

The literal `'Z'` won't match the string `UTC`.